# Custom Auth provider - pass data to `getUserInfo` from `handleCallback`

Tags: auth-provider

I have a custom Auth Provider used by Connected App where the data **that salesforce expects** to be returned in the `getUserInfo` method is actually sent along with the OAUTH2 state **(that data is coming from my mobile application)** (it's signed with a digital cert so authenticity can be validated).

However, I am struggling as to how I can pass any data from `handleCallback` to `getUserInfo`?

Note: this is for interactive logins via my custom connected app, not for Named Credentials and callouts to HTTP servers.

I can't call to my service in getUserInfo because my service never has this data. The data is on the mobile device in the hands of the user.
Note: we can trust this data because it is signed with vendor attested certificate and the signature is verified by Salesforce through my service.

Comment: Have you tried to store the data as additional state in the Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse you create in handleCallback which is then (perhaps) available in getUserInfo?

Comment: @PhilW where's the additional state? That class has 4 properties - Provider name, refresh token, access token and state (state here being the `initialStateToPropagate` from `initialize()` method, passing anything else into this `state` causes OAUTH error `invalid state` in the UI for the user)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You may not be able to, but can you extend this class and cast what you receive in getUserInfo to your specialized version?

Comment: I tried, i get `Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended: Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse`

Comment: Yeah, as I feared. Hmmm. I can't think of any other ways to safely tunnel the data, so perhaps you'll just have to re-query that data from your external service?

Comment: @PhilW the whole point of my service is that it never has this data in the first place. This way the data is only between the user and SF, and not stored in any external service.

Comment: I am confused. That I don't get from your question... if the data is available to the callback, doesn't that mean it is coming from your service? If not, where is it coming from and why is there a need to pass it from the callback handler to getUserInfo? Please [edit] your question to explain better.

Comment: @PhilW see my edits